# Child tag is absolute, and its margin-left is begin from padding of the parent tag. Why is its margin-right beginning from body?

Tags: html, css

This is margin range from chrome:
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.article {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #999;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-right: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  padding: 20px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

img {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="left">sldkfjlsj</div>
  <div class="middle">lksdflmsddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssslksmflmsgmfmg;df;g,df;gl,f;,gd;fl,g;fl,g;ldf,;gldf;mgkdfgdfmgpfmgpsomgpsmgpspgmspmgosmgmspgomsgmspgmspgomspgmpsogflmsldfmsldmflsfm</div>
  <div class="right"><img src="glm.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Begin I think the reason is the width of father tag is not solid. I try it, but no effect. And then I try set relative to father tag and the margin-right is begin from body, also not symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing and matching.
for absolute positioning what matters is left, top, right, bottom, width and height.
But my guess is that you don't need it.
What you are trying to achieve is a column of text in the middle of .article with some sides.

You will almost achieve it if you drop the absolute positioning of .middle.
then the margins on it will start where you want. And you'll be left with figuring out the offsets.

```css
body {margin: 0px; padding:20px; position:relative;}
.article { background-color: #eee; padding:20px; border:2px solid #999; overflow: hidden;}
.left {position: absolute; top:40px; left:40px; width:160px; padding:20px; border: 2px solid #999; background-color: #fff;}
.right {position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 40px; padding: 20px; width: 80px; background-color: #fff; border: 2px solid #999;}
.middle { margin-left: 220px; margin-right: 180px; background-color: #fff; border: 2px solid #999; padding:20px; word-break: break-all;}
img {width:80px;}
```

```html
<div class = "article">
    <div class = "left">sldkfjlsj</div>
    <div class = "middle">lksdflmsddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssslksmflmsgmfmg;df;g,df;gl,f;,gd;fl,g;fl,g;ldf,;gldf;mgkdfgdfmgpfmgpsomgpsmgpspgmspmgosmgmspgomsgmspgmspgomspgmpsogflmsldfmsldmflsfm</div>
    <div class="right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-h-c-80-120-10.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

[A good article about css positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: Do you kow why it like that if it is absolute?

Comment: Yeah, with your setup all your absolute positioned elements are tied to html element.. which does not have padding so the width of element with margins will be full width of the browser. And since you don't give any coordinates to .middle to tie to it is placed where it would be in the flow.